# Remove text from columns that may or may not be present multiple times

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, update, replace

I have the following table in SQL Server 2008.

```
create table OrgUnits
(
    OrgUnitId int not null constraint PK_OrgUnits1 primary key,
    OrgUnitName varchar(100),
    OrgUnitLevel int not null,
    OrgUnitKey varchar(100) constraint UQ_OrgUnits_OrgUnitKey unique,
    Level1Id int not null,
    Level2Id int,
    StatusId int not null constraint FK_OrgUnits_Status references Status,
    VersionNumber int not null
);

INSERT INTO OrgUnits (OrgUnitId, OrgUnitName, OrgUnitKey, Level1Id, Level2Id,
                      StatusId, VersionNumber) 
VALUES 
(218824, 'Company1 (5) (5) (5)', '5', 218824, 1, 1),
(218825, 'Division1 (1) (1) (1)', '1', 218825, 1, 1),
(218826, 'XAVAT (4) (4) (4)', '4', 218826, 1, 1),
(218827, 'WATe (7) (7) (7)', '7', 218827, 1, 1),
(218828, 'Communications', '05-905-6320-300', 218824, 218828, 1, 1),
(218829, 'Corporate Development', '05-955-6320-300', 218824, 218829, 1, 1),
(218830, 'Corporate Board of Directors', '05-111-3515-301', 218830, 1, 1);
```

Ideally I'd have `OrgUnitName` appear like `OrgUnitName + ' (' + OrgUnitKey + ')';`
But it appears like that update has been run on some but not all the values in the table.

What would the update statement be to update all rows so they would have the correct format? Please note I have hundreds of rows and this is only to fix an earlier issue a previous update caused. The query only needs to be run once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Something like this?**

```
UPDATE dbo.OrgUnits
SET OrgUnitName = RTRIM(REPLACE(OrgUnitName,'('+OrgUnitKey+')',''))+' (' + OrgUnitKey + ')';
```

**View the result**

```
SELECT  OrgUnitName from dbo.OrgUnits;
```

**Result**

```
OrgUnitName
Company1 (5)
Division1 (1)
XAVAT (4)
WATe (7)
Communications (05-905-6320-300)
Corporate Development (05-955-6320-300)
Corporate Board of Directors (05-111-3515-301)
```

Comment: Spectacular. Worked like a charm. Thanks. If you don't mind could you explain it, just so I have the knowledge.

Comment: Hey @MarkD no problem! Well, the `replace()` takes care of each `OrgUnitKey` currently inside the `OrgUnitName` and the corresponding parentheses, and turns them into empty strings. After that there are some trailing spaces, they get romeved with the `RTRIM()`. At this point the `OrgUnitName` should be clear of `OrgUnitKey`'s and should be uniform accross all records.  From here we we can add the `OrgUnitKey` again, together with the parentheses.